# Raspberry Pi Zero as webcam

Tags: usb, kernel, pi-zero-w, webcam, gadget

I read some case, like using dwc2 and g_webcam in `/boot/config` and cmdline. but hard to understand and doesn't work. and can't find a tutorial, there are some tutorials only about serial and ethernet.

Does anyone know a tutorial or link about Raspberry Pi zero usb gadget as webcam? And some explanation about [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt)?

Comment: I also tried the obvious way: Enabling camera module and use the g_webcam module. But the only thing I got was nothing and panics.

Comment: A link that might help, where the person has figured it out with video proof:
http://www.davidhunt.ie/raspberry-pi-zero-with-pi-camera-as-usb-webcam/

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone in this matter. That said, perhaps this [COMPOSITE USB GADGETS ON THE RASPBERRY PI ZERO](http://isticktoit.net/?p=1383) is what you need. I don't have the need to setup a webcam on my Rpi0 yet, so I can't confirm if this will help. Please do let us know how it turns out.